# What happens when Cassandra is unable to add new data to primary replica

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Assume we have 3 nodes in Cassandra with different storage sizes, RF=2, and CL=QUORUM.

New data is inserted and the partitioner hashes the new key to node 1. Although node 1 is available, it has no more storage space, but the other 2 nodes do. Does Cassandra write the data to nodes 2 and 3 instead?

If so, how does this affect your read path? When a user queries for that specific partition key, will it hash to node 1, fail to find it, then try all other nearby nodes in the token ring? Or fail all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is placed in to C* based on partition key but this data also defines the replicas which the data belongs to as well. This means there is never any doubt as to what nodes a piece of data resides on.

If RF=2 then each partition key will map to exactly two nodes in the cluster. This mapping will not change unless the topology of the cluster changes, or the replication factor of the keyspace is changed.

When you insert a piece of data you specify a Consistency Level. This is the required number of replica acknowledgements that must be received from the Cluster for the request to be considered successful.

In your case Quorum is equivalent to ALL (Quorum = 1/2 * RF + 1 == 2 == ALL). This means any writes will fail if either of the replicas is down or unable to take new writes. If the write cannot be completed for whatever reason it is considered failed on that replica.

IF CL < RF, then hints will be stored for the node which is down. When the node comes back online, or is able to receive writes again, the hints will be delivered by coordinating node for that write.

On read a similar thing will take place. Both replicas will be queried for the data, but since one is shut down, the consistency level will not be met and the request will fail.

Comment: Going back to: In your case Qurorum is equivalent to ALL (Qurourm = 1/2 * RF + 1 == 2 == ALL)

In my case, the node isn't actually down, it's online but unable to accept any more data. Are you saying that failing to write to node 1 in case of storage constraints is equivalent to a node being down?

Comment: For writes yes. Although you most likely would run into issues long before the disk was full because of compaction.